# Crash when opening app after being in background for a while

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is an issue I've been trying to tackle for a little while. When opening my app after being in the background (and I assume being killed to use its resources), I get this crash:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{package_path/package_path.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong state class, expecting View State but received class android.os.Bundle instead. This usually happens when two views of different type have the same id in the same hierarchy. This view's id is id/nav_watching_queue. Make sure other views do not use the same id.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong state class, expecting View State but received class android.os.Bundle instead. This usually happens when two views of different type have the same id in the same hierarchy. This view's id is id/nav_watching_queue. Make sure other views do not use the same id.
    at android.view.View.onRestoreInstanceState(View.java:15776)
    at com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBarTab.onRestoreInstanceState(BottomBarTab.java:555)
    at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:15751)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3231)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3237)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3237)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3237)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3237)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3237)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3237)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3237)
    at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:15729)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:2106)
    at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1047)
    at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1002)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1174)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2638)
    ... 9 more
```

I have checked and there is only one view with the id `nav_watching_queue`. Knowing that my activity is being re-created in this situation, my onCreate() logic checks if there is a pre-existing fragment in the Fragment Manager before creating a new one like so:

```
if (App.getInstance().isInitializing()) {
        SeriesFragment seriesFragment;

        if (SharedPrefsHelper.getInstance().isLoggedIn()) {
            seriesFragment = UserListFragment.newInstance();
        } else {
            seriesFragment = SeasonsFragment.newInstance();
            defaultTabId = R.id.nav_seasons;
        }

        SenpaiExportHelper senpaiExportHelper = new SenpaiExportHelper(seriesFragment);
        senpaiExportHelper.getSeasonList();

        startFragment(seriesFragment);
    } else {
        if (getCurrentFragment() == null) {
            if (getIntent() != null && getIntent().hasExtra("notificationClicked")) {
                defaultTabId = R.id.nav_watching_queue;
                startFragment(BacklogFragment.newInstance());
            } else {
                startFragment(UserListFragment.newInstance());
            }
        }
    }
```

---

```
private Fragment getCurrentFragment() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments() != null && !getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().isEmpty()) {
        Iterator iterator = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().iterator();
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) iterator.next();
        Fragment previousFragment = fragment;

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            fragment = (Fragment) iterator.next();

            if (fragment == null) {
                fragment = previousFragment;
            } else {
                previousFragment = fragment;
            }
        }

        return fragment;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I cannot reliably recreate this scenario either. I have "Do Not Keep Activities" enabled in my emulator's settings but I do not get this exception when re-opening the app.